# Is there any graphical meta data for SO, or a way for us users to build one?

Tags: discussion, meta

I'd love to have something like [github / steam's graphs](https://github.com/blog/1093-introducing-the-new-github-graphs) for SO. Failing that, I'd love a full-featured API (again, [a la github](https://developer.github.com/v3/)) for which to build something like this. Is there any such thing? Failing that, is the API robust enough to provide for this data if I wanted to make an app to show this data?

Thanks for any pointers!

Comment: "Is the API robust enough" seems like a very broad question, especially when your desired results aren't particularly well defined. [Have you read through the API's documentation?](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs) Have you tried making such an app, and where did you get stuck?

Comment: Sure, the Data Explorer is a start. you can easily tack on graphical stuff . see this example - h http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/225376/164243

Comment: @DavidRobinson - the question isn't intended to be specific, and this question isn't intended to solicit technical help. However, perhaps I was being a bit too broad. I have read through a decent amount of the API docs, but I was hoping for some analogies from folks that had used it before I dove into it.

Comment: @Coffee Thanks for the link, that's very helpful! I'll check it out.